# How to make filename with "+" downloadable in IIS

Tags: windows, iis, mime-types

I want to make file "gcc-c++-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64.rpm" downloadable in Internet Information Services (IIS). I tried adding MIME type as '*', but it didn't help.
Is there any way I can make filename having '+' symbol or any other symbol downloadable?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the characters?

Comment: You can escape the + using %2B. Regardless, I would expect the + to remain unchanged unless it is after the query string.

Comment: Why not just rename the file to have cpp instead of c++ and not try and solve every problem technically :-) user is probably aware of what they are downloading anyways ...

Answer (score 0):

Resolution

To resolve this issue, follow below instructions:

```
in the IIS webserver section, double click the 'Request Filtering' icon
in the 'File Name Extension' right click->Edit Feature Settings...' the file 'web.config'
check the option 'Allow double escaping' (this option is unchecked by defualt)
repeat all above 3 steps for the 'defualt website' (or whatever you have given the name to your site)
re-start the IIS
you should now be able to open up the file name having '+' in its name.
```